# Parameter 1 of constructor in required a bean of type 'org.springframework.social.connect.ConnectionRepository' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to use Spring social to connect to facebook. 
This is the error that I am getting:

```
Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in Application.Facebook.FacebookController required a bean of type 'org.springframework.social.connect.ConnectionRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.social.connect.ConnectionRepository' in your configuration.
```

This is the tutorial I followed: https://stackabuse.com/how-to-access-the-facebook-api-with-java-and-spring-boot/

It simply does not work b/c it's giving me the error mentioned above

I tried cloning the repo here: https://github.com/DavidLandup/HowToAccessFacebookAPIWithSpringBoot
and it doesn't work

structure:

```
main
    +- java
       +- Application
          +- Facebook
             +- FacebookController.java
          +- Application.java
```

FacebookController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class FacebookController {

    private Facebook facebook;
    private ConnectionRepository connectionRepository;

    public FacebookController(Facebook facebook, ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
        this.facebook = facebook;
        this.connectionRepository = connectionRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String helloFacebook(Model model) {
        if (connectionRepository.findPrimaryConnection(Facebook.class) == null) {
            return "redirect:/connect/fb";
        }

        model.addAttribute("facebookProfile", facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile());
        PagedList<Post> feed = facebook.feedOperations().getFeed();
        model.addAttribute("feed", feed);
        return "feed";
    }
}
```

Application.java

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.6.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

bootJar {
    baseName = 'gs-spring-boot'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile(
            'org.springframework.social:spring-social-core:1.1.6.RELEASE',
            'org.springframework.social:spring-social-facebook:2.0.3.RELEASE',
            'org.springframework.social:spring-social-twitter:1.1.0.RELEASE',
            'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web',
            'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    )
}
```

The full error msg:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.6.RELEASE)

2019-09-26 13:20:24.043  INFO 88576 --- [           main]
2019-09-26 13:20:24.047  INFO 88576 --- [           main] Application.Application                  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-09-26 13:20:25.113  INFO 88576 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-09-26 13:20:25.149  INFO 88576 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-09-26 13:20:25.149  INFO 88576 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.21]
2019-09-26 13:20:25.286  INFO 88576 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-09-26 13:20:25.286  INFO 88576 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1194 ms
2019-09-26 13:20:25.384  WARN 88576 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'facebookController' defined in file [/Users/user/Social_Media_Integration/backend/out/production/classes/Application/Facebook/FacebookController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.social.connect.ConnectionRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
2019-09-26 13:20:25.388  INFO 88576 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-09-26 13:20:25.401  INFO 88576 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-09-26 13:20:25.586 ERROR 88576 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in Application.Facebook.FacebookController required a bean of type 'org.springframework.social.connect.ConnectionRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.social.connect.ConnectionRepository' in your configuration.
```

**UPDATE**
here is the full error log:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils.extractFullFilenameFromUrlPath(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController.getPathExtension(ConnectController.java:416) ~[spring-social-web-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar:1.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController.connectionStatusRedirect(ConnectController.java:389) ~[spring-social-web-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar:1.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController.oauth2Callback(ConnectController.java:285) ~[spring-social-web-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar:1.1.4.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
```

Comment: you don't have any `ConnectionRepository` in source

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems in Spring Boot 2, they removed the **FacebookAutoConfiguration** configurer from spring-boot-autoconfigure dependency, so if you want to enable this (and make spring setup the necessary beans) you have to define a **SocialConfigurer**:

```
@Configuration
public class SocialConfig implements SocialConfigurer {

    @Value("${spring.social.facebook.appId}")
    private String appId;
    @Value("${spring.social.facebook.appSecret}")
    private String appSecret;

    @Override
    public void addConnectionFactories(final ConnectionFactoryConfigurer cfConfig, final Environment env) {
        cfConfig.addConnectionFactory(new FacebookConnectionFactory(appId, appSecret));
    }

    @Override
    public UserIdSource getUserIdSource() {
        return new SessionUserIdSource();
    }

    @Override
    public UsersConnectionRepository getUsersConnectionRepository(final ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator) {
        return new InMemoryUsersConnectionRepository(connectionFactoryLocator);
    }
}
```

And add the **@EnableSocial** annotation to your Application class:

```
@EnableSocial
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here is the latest documentation from spring (altough it does seem to be missing some information and contains broken link to Spring Social):

https://docs.spring.io/spring-social-facebook/docs/2.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/

Also in your controller, you seem to be autowiring the Facebook object. Is there a bean definition somewhere in your code or where does that get created?
In the official documentation I linked above, the example snippet shows the creation of Facebook object as a FacebookTemplate like this:

```
String accessToken = "f8FX29g..."; // access token received from Facebook after OAuth authorization
Facebook facebook = new FacebookTemplate(accessToken);
```

**Update:**
I've added a test project on github. If you fill your appId and secretId in the application.properties, it should work (Currently, I've only implemented the feed listing)
https://github.com/gybandi/facebooktest

**Update 2:**
The error log you linked is caused by the older spring-social-web depedency (which comes from spring-web-starter as a transitive depedency).
Try to include the correct **spring-social-config** dependency in your gradle script:

```
...
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile(
            'org.springframework.social:spring-social-core:1.1.6.RELEASE',
            'org.springframework.social:spring-social-config:1.1.6.RELEASE', 
            'org.springframework.social:spring-social-facebook:2.0.3.RELEASE',
            'org.springframework.social:spring-social-twitter:1.1.0.RELEASE',
            'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web',
            'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    )
}
...
```

Comment: I got everything to run but when i'm trying to load the fb page it's giving me this error: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils.extractFullFilenameFromUrlPath(Ljava/lang/String;)`
doing some research it seems that this method is deprecated in spring 4.3.2, does that mean I have to revert my spring-boot version to an older version or is there a workaround?

Comment: that's weird. what calls that method? could you paste the stack trace? I've used the 2.1.8.RELEASE spring boot starter parent (which has spring 5.1.9.RELEASE) with the same social/facebook dependecies as you, but I haven't encountered that issue

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I've added the full error log to the the description above