# Spring 5 with Spring-social reports java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils.extractFullFilenameFromUrlPath

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, java-8, spring-social-facebook, tomcat8.5

I have tested Spring 5.0.0.RELEASE to 5.3.4 and all failed with the latest spring social with Facebook login and all reported this error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils.extractFullFilenameFromUrlPath(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

I looked at all JARs & it seems that the static method of  **WebUtils.extractFullFilenameFromUrlPath** doesn't exists in 5.x.x. BTW. I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58134798/13119575) and it failed too; Spring still attempts to invoke the method

On the other hand, Spring 4.x.x worked like a charm

It should be noted that I am not using Spring Boot
Plz help

Comment: Spring Social isn't supported anymore (has been in the attic for a while already).

Comment: I suspect that you are correct. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Try using latest spring-webflow version.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.webflow/spring-webflow -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).